# async twisted, synchronous requests per domain (with delay)

Tags: web-scraping, async-await, python-requests, twisted, python-3.7

let's say i have 10 domains, but every domain need to have delay between requests (to avoid dos situations and ip-banning).

I was thinking about async twisted that call a class, requests from requests module have delay(500) , but then another request to the same domain make it delay(250) and so on, and so on.

How to achive that static delay, and store somewhere something like queue for every domain (class) ?

It's custom web scraper, twisted is TCP but this shouldn't make difference. I don't want the code, but knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while using `asyncio` for async,

```
import asyncio

async def nested(x):
    print(x)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    # Schedule nested() to run soon concurrently
    # with "main()".
    for x in range(100):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        task = asyncio.create_task(nested(x))
        # "task" can now be used to cancel "nested()", or
        # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
        await task




asyncio.run(main())
```

with *await* in main, it will print every 2s,

without *await* in nasted, it will print every 1s.

without *await task* in main, it will print every 0s, even *asyncio.sleep* is declared.

*It is totally hard to maintain if we are new in async.*